# Is there a stackexchange site for healthy or poisoning food questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, food-safety, stackexchange

I just joined Seasoned Advice, I read the [tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and it states:

> Don't ask about... [...] General health, diet, and nutritional topics (e.g. "Is cauliflower healthy?")

Well, bummer, I got a question regarding the risk/dangerosity of a retail food product (i.e.: not cooked by myself): **is there a stackexchange site where I can ask about such topics?**

<sub>(this meta question is a general question, but if you're curious about what I had in mind, it was about [the after-effects of eating mooncakes](http://www.ejinsight.com/20170929-a-few-reminders-before-you-take-a-bite-of-that-mooncake/).)</sub>

Comment: It may be easier to get an answer if you actually say what your question is. :)

Comment: @Catija on Meta? Not the right place to ask a non-Meta question. :)

Comment: There's a difference between asking the question and being specific in your meta question. :D You're not looking for answers to your question here, you're looking for answers to "where should I ask this"... but it's difficult to tell you where to ask it if we don't know what the question is.

Comment: If you gather enough evidence and has a specific claim, you could also probably ask it on [skeptics.se] though...

Comment: Do you mean a food that's actually dangerous as produced, or something that's contaminated or spoiled?

Comment: @TerryCarmen I was thinking of dangerous food at the time of the purchase: it's not perished, but you eat it, you get sick. Possibly due to the ingredients chosen, or the production technique.

Comment: @Cœur Aside from actual food allergies, I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: @TerryCarmen your country, USA, has the FDA. My country had 40-years old frozen meat, rat meat, motor oil, adulterated milk for kids, etc. _[Around 294,000 babies in China became ill after drinking the milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_adulteration_in_China)_. Buying food here is a gamble for life or death.

Comment: @Cœur You didn't say where you lived. Yes, there are quite a few places where the food can kill you. I have no short-term suggestions, since much of the food is contaminated when/where it's produced and some is contaminated by the ground that it grows in. Long-term, the Chinese people will need to pressure the government and food producers to clean up the environment and food production methods. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: **Thank you very much for actually taking the tour before posting!**

That said, our sister site [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com) could be what you are looking for. From their [help](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> If your question is about...
>
> - Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health
> - The ways that diseases and injuries affect people
> - The health effects of processes such as pregnancy and aging
> - Medications and other interventions that are used to treat diseases

Note that they won’t give *individual* advice.

Comment: I'd also note that the question the OP wanted to ask may be off topic there, and certainly a ton of the health/nutrition questions we've seen here would be. They don't want "is X healthy?", that want specific, answerable questions.

Comment: That's the old tour text .. we intend to change that and remove _all_ nutrition related questions from healthsciences.se